# Can we create map with out creating tranformer class on gateway in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, transformer-model

```
<int:gateway id="com_java__TestService" service-interface="com.java.svc.TestService">
    <int:method name="testOperation" payload-expression="@convertObjectToMap.transformer(#args[0],#args[1])"  reply-channel="replyChannel_testOperation" request-channel="requestChannel_testOperation"/>

  </int:gateway>
```

In above code snipped two parameter is coming from testOpeartion method of gateway and the reply-channel of this gateway is expecting map. So we want to convert object type parameters into map.

I have written transformer which returning map. And the requirement is to create map in spring configuration xml itself. I don't want to write any transformer class to convert map.

currently we have created custom convertObjectToMap bean which has transformer method which expected two parameter and it returns map.

can we cretae map with out using java transformer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe what your transformer actually does, and what the arguments are.

If it's simply `#args[0]` is the key and `#args[1]` is the value and it's a map with just one value then

```
"T(java.util.Collections).singletonMap(#args[0], #args[1])"
```

should work.

Comment: Transformer takes the two argument from testOperation method and it convert into map. And the type of argument is object type.


I have apllied the code which you have suggest but when we run it gives below error 

 org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 0): Type cannot be found 'java.utils.Collections'

Comment: Sorry - typo - `java.util.Collections`.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some r&d we found the solution of above question.
Please find code snipped below

```
<int:gateway id="com_java__TestService" service-interface="com.java.svc.TestService">
    <int:method name="testOperation" payload-expression="#args[0]"  reply-channel="replyChannel_testOperation" request-channel="requestChannel_testOperation">
 <int:header expression="#args[0]" name="fxlPayload"/>
      <int:header expression="#args[1]" name="fxlHeader"/>
    </int:method>
  </int:gateway>
```

also we add one transformer and enricher in chain.
This chain will start executing after gateway

```
 <int:transformer expression="new java.util.HashMap()"/>
    <int:enricher>
      <int:property expression="headers['fxlPayload']" name="Payload"/>
      <int:property expression="headers['fxlHeader']" name="Header"/>
    </int:enricher>
```